# Semaphore fairness setting

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying the understand the fairness setting of Semaphore(int num, boolean how).
I have this program.Where the fairness setting seems to be not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        shared sh=new shared();
        Semaphore sm=new Semaphore(1,true);
        newthread1 nh1=new  newthread1(sm,sh,"nh1");

        newthread1 nh3=new newthread1(sm, sh,"nh3");
        newthread1 nh2=new newthread1(sm, sh,"nh2");
        }
}



Class shared:-

public class shared {

    public void msg()
    {
        for(int i=65;i<68;i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " " + (char)i);

        }
    }

}

    class new thread:-
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class newthread1 implements Runnable  {
    shared sh=null;
    Semaphore sem=null;
    Thread t=null;
    String name=null;
    public newthread1(Semaphore sem,shared sh,String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.sem=sem;
        this.sh=sh;
        this.name=name;

        t=new Thread(this,name);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            sem.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" has accuqired the lock");
        sh.msg();

        sem.release();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
```

Please correct my understanding here:-
My understanding that waiting thread should get the lock,the order they have requested for lock.if i run the program  it does not give me the correct result.
every time gives different result.

Thank You

Comment: One observation is that you can't really know what order they request the lock. You don't know the threads call the `acquire` method in the exact order you start them.

Answer (score 0):

You may think that the order in which you start the threads matters. It does not. What matters is which thread arrives at the `sem.acquire()` call first.

The fairness setting of the `Semaphore` is of little help here.